# How to update a JSON file after reading it in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

In app.js, I'm only reading the traffic.json file but I need to update the traffic.json file. When I click the submit button, I'm getting the previous data instead of the new data.

**Area.html:**

```
var jsonURL = "http://192.168.7.123:3000/traffic";

    d3.json(jsonURL, function(error, data){ 
alert(data);
 ....
 ....
});
```

**app.js:**

```
app.get('/traffic',function(req,res) {
  res.sendfile('views/traffic.json');
});
```

**traffic.json:**

```
[ { "client_ip" : "1.0.230.145" , "timestamp" : "1341667450773" , "total_traffic" : 0} , { "client_ip" : "1.0.230.145" , "timestamp" : "1341667450786" , "total_traffic" : 3} , { "client_ip" : "1.0.230.145" , "timestamp" : "1341667451076" , "total_traffic" : 4} , { "client_ip" : "1.0.230.145" , "timestamp" : "1341667451104" , "total_traffic" : 7} , { "client_ip" : "1.0.230.145" , "timestamp" : "1341667451128" , "total_traffic" : 10}]
```

How do I update the traffic.json file so that after clicking submit, I get the newly updated data?

Answer (score 0):

You can `JSON.stingify()` your new data and save it to the `traffic.json` using [fs.writeFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) or [fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options)

```
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/traffic',function(req,res) {
  // I don't know what information you need to save. IP of the client that clicked button?
  fs.writeFileSync('views/traffic.json', JSON.stringify(newData)); 
  res.sendfile('views/traffic.json');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to save to the json file?

Comment: Thanks for your info., we are storing JSONArray in to the file ex above json, it comes from web service call. we tried JSON.stringifyy() it converts into string, So d3.json() method wont display the graph due to string object instead of json. My problem is when ever jsonURL is executed it is not getting new data from json file.

Comment: when I call a webservice call,I'm trying to store the json data into traffic.json file.I'm able to get the modified data into traffic.json file after a webservice call.In this URL,"http://192.168.7.123:3000/traffic"; I'm able to get the modified data over here.d3.json(jsonURL, function(error, data){ 
alert(data);
 ....
 ....
});                                                                                                              But here, I'm unable to get the modified data in "data" variable.I'm getting the previous data in the "data" variable.

Comment: I want to get the new data to be stored in "data" variable of this function. d3.json(jsonURL, function(error, data){ alert(data); .... .... });